# Recursively reduce list of tuples

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

So I have a list of tuples like so:

```
[
    ('Worksheet',),
    ('1a', 'Calculated'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1b', 'General'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 1'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 2'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1c', 'General'),
    ('1c', 'General', 'Basic'),
    ('1c', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('2', 'Active'),
    ('2', 'Active', 'Passive'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ...
]
```

Each tuple will be 1-5 in length. I need to recursively reduce the list to end up with this:

```
[
    ('Worksheet',),
    ('1a', 'Calculated'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 1'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 2'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1c', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('2', 'Active', 'Passive'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ...
]
```

Basically if the next line matches all from the previous line +1 remove it up to the max length for tuples that have the same hierarchy.

So as seen in my example there were 3 lines where `1c` was the first item in the tuple so it was reduced to the longest.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_subtuple(tup1, tup2):
    '''Return True if all the elements of tup1 are consecutively in tup2.'''
    if len(tup2) < len(tup1): return False
    try:
        offset = tup2.index(tup1[0])
    except ValueError:
        return False
    # This could be wrong if tup1[0] is in tup2, but doesn't start the subtuple.
    # You could solve this by recurring on the rest of tup2 if this is false, but
    # it doesn't apply to your input data.
    return tup1 == tup2[offset:offset+len(tup1)]
```

Then, just filter your input list (named `l` here):

```
[t for i, t in enumerate(l) if not any(is_subtuple(t, t2) for t2 in l[i+1:])]
```

Now, this list comprehension assumes that the input list is ordered consistently the way you show it, with the subtuples being earlier than the tuples they're in. It's also a bit expensive (`O(n**2)`, I think), but it'll get the job done.

Comment: I like this! Could you give me an example based on the commented text you added to your code?

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx `[(a,b,c), (a,a,b,c)]` for defined a, b and c

Comment: I see where you are going with this but I am having a hard time putting it into context. Could you show me with the code you provided above? Thanks a again!

Answer (score 1):

Grouping the tuples on the first element; use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (with [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for ease of creating a key.

Then filter each group separately:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

def filtered_group(group):
    group = list(group)
    maxlen = max(len(l) for l in group)
    return [l for l in group if len(l) == maxlen]

filtered = [filtered_group(g) for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
output = list(chain.from_iterable(filtered))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def filtered_group(group):
...     group = list(group)
...     maxlen = max(len(l) for l in group)
...     return [l for l in group if len(l) == maxlen]
... 
>>> filtered = [filtered_group(g) for k, g in groupby(inputlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
>>> pprint(list(chain.from_iterable(filtered)))
[('Worksheet',),
 ('1a', 'Calculated'),
 ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
 ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 1'),
 ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 2'),
 ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
 ('1c', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
 ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
 ('2', 'Active', 'Passive'),
 ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None')]
```

Comment: This kills `('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 1')`.

Comment: @kojiro: ah, you need the first one that is length 5, or the last one available?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters - Thanks for the quick reply! I am however getting an error message: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: I dunno, I'm trying to figure out the "rules" myself.

Comment: I'd go with, basically, "filter out all the tuples that are subtuples of another tuple." (Here, when I say *subtuple* I mean it like *substring*.)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint

l=[
    ('Worksheet',),
    ('1a', 'Calculated'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1b', 'General'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 1'),
    ('1b', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data', 'Line 2'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('1c', 'General'),
    ('1c', 'General', 'Basic'),
    ('1c', 'General', 'Basic', 'Data'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'),
    ('2', 'Active'),
    ('2', 'Active', 'Passive'),
    ('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None')
    #...
]

i=0
while i<len(l)-1:
  l0=l[i]
  l1=l[i+1]
  if len(l1)==len(l0)+1 and l1[:-1]==l0:
    del l[i]
  else:
    i+=1

pprint(l)
```

Logic: Compare every line (except the last) against the next one. Should the next be the same with one additional item, remove the first. Otherwise, advance to the next pair of lines.

This is not a recursive solution, but could be reworked to one. It's a filter operation where you need the next item in the condition.

Just for fun, here is a Haskell version that is recursive (this type of recursion is efficient in Haskell and Scheme, but not Python):

```
prefixfilt :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
prefixfilt [] = []
prefixfilt [x] = [x]
prefixfilt (x0:x1:xs) =
    if x0 == init x1 then rest else (x0:rest)
    where rest = prefixfilt (x1:xs)
```

Comment: This does in fact produce the output that I want so thank you! I'm working to see if I can make it recursive. The list of tuples I will be working with will be much longer and much more complicated so recursion would be best. Thanks again!